# Django REST framework receive "bad" DecimalField but don't error out

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a piece of code that needs to take POSTs from a ColdFusion system which is very inflexible when it comes to JSON, and I don't have much control over it anyhow. I have a problem where sometimes an automated system running on ColdFusion will send "empty" DecimalFields as "". This causes a validation error in Django because DecimalFields cannot be converted from an empty string:

```
TOTAL_DEFECTS = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null = True)
```

JSON that fails it...

```
"TOTAL_DEFECTS":"",
```

That should just produce a null field, but instead, it errors out, saying that's not valid. Technically it isn't since, of course, you can't do this in Python:

```
import decimal
decimal.Decimal("")
```

In order to handle this, I have hacked into the dispatch routine of the viewset. I was wondering if there's a better way to do this. Hack-y code:

```
@csrf_exempt # Because ColdFusion can't handle CSRF headers
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    repregex = re.compile(r'"",') # This is actually done elsewhere in the real code
    nbody = repregex.sub('null,', request.body)
    request._body = nbody
    request._stream = BytesIO(nbody)
    a = super(XViewSet, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if a.status_code != 201:
        #log errors here
        pass
    return a
```

This works for this specific case but I think is probably about as far from ideal as I can get. Is there a more Django-ish way to do this other than rewriting this HttpRequest object that isn't meant to be rewritten?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way! Your answer is to [customize the `CharField` options](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield) in the serializer. I would use [additional arguments](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) to keep the code DRY, here's how:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView


class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'TOTAL_DEFECTS': {'allow_blank': True}}


class MyView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

Of course you would have to switch `MyModel`, `MyView` and `MySerializer` with your actual serializer and view.

Comment: In my case, this fails with the following error: "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_blank'"

Comment: @moulde try asking in a separate question, and include the full trace back, and model details

Comment: I'm not asking a question, I'm just adding to your answer, that (at least for version 3.7.0 of DRF) Decimal_Field does not take a allow_blank parameter. Hence the error.